# Where I should put my python scripts in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, open-source

My python program consists of several files:

- the main execution python script
- python modules in *.py files
- config file
- log files
- executables scripts of other languages.

All this files should be available only for root. The main script should run on startup, e.g. via upstart.
**Where I should put all this files in Linux filesystem? 

What's the better way for distribution my program?** pip, easy_install, deb, ...? I haven't worked with any of these tool, so I want something easy for me.
The minimum supported Linux distributive should be Ubuntu.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For sure, if this program is to be available only for `root`, then the main execution python script have to go to `/usr/sbin/`.

Config files ought to go to `/etc/`, and log files to `/var/log/`.

Other python files should be deployed to `/usr/share/pyshared/`.

Executable scripts of other languages will go either in `/usr/bin/` or `/usr/sbin/` depending on whether they should be available to all users, or for root only.

Comment: Thanks, but how to make auto location all files in appropriate directories when I give archive with these files to other people? So people who get my program don't move files by themselves.

Comment: I guess the best option will be to create a `.deb` package for Ubuntu. You'll be able to place all files at the locations you want.

Answer (score 2):

If only root should access the scripts, why not put it in /root/ ?
Secondly, if you're going to distribute your application you'll probably need easy_install or something similar, otherwise just tar.gz the stuff if only a few people will access it?

It all depends on your scale..
Pyglet, wxPython and similar have a hughe userbase.. same for BeautifulSoup but they still tar.gz the stuff and you just use setuptools to deply it (whcih, is another option).